# How to update Laravel database while using inner join in a migration

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, database-migration

I have the following SQL statement which is working directly in SQL console, but I need to make it on a Laravel Migration.

> Short story, I am trying to replace the current value of columnA on
> tableA with id of the corresponding value in columnB of the tableB.

The Tables structure is the following:

```
tableA:
    id: int(11)
    columnA: varchar(191)

tableB:
    id: int(11)
    columnB: varchar(191)
```

The SQL Statement which is working on SQL console:

```
UPDATE tableA INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.columnA = tableB.columnB SET tableA.columnA=tableB.id WHERE tableB.columnB = tableA.columnA
```

I was thinking it is working with a raw statement:

```
DB::raw(UPDATE tableA INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.columnA = tableB.columnB SET tableA.columnA=tableB.id WHERE tableB.columnB = tableA.columnA);
```

Now I am stacked on creating the Laravel Migration, when I tried to run the migrate, nothing happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `DB::statement` instead of `DB::raw`, the second one does not run the query.

Comment: I can accept the answer only after the next 5 minutes, but I will definitely accept!